# UICollectionView 3x in one row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make an app that will show images in a UICollectionView, each row there must be 3 images. I've tried different a way like taking the whole view width and dividing it by 3, but it did not work for devices other than the iPhone 6+. Is there anyway I can make it such that it would be able to. One example of what I am trying to do is the instagrame timeline or suggested photos where the photos are in a 3x grid.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea of taking the whole width and dividing by 3. You have to find the screen size within the code.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 50)
        return size
    }
}
```

You might also have to play with `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` and `insetForSectionAtIndex` to get the size and margins exactly the way you want it.